# Hibernate: how to force a single query for all nested attributes?

Tags: hibernate

*** This question has been updated with a complete model and more focused question thanks to @christian-beikov

If I query for the Moose entity by Id, the query that is generated will join the first Mooseling (including the related Gooseling) in a single query, but the second Mooseling.Gooseling will be queried in a second SELECT statement.

It's clear from the debug output that it determines that mooseling2.gooseling is "deemed to be circular".  Is there a way to override this and force it to load the whole tree in one query?

I tried the @NamedEntityGraph on the Moose object, but that didn't change anything.

```
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     : Static SQL for entity: com.fetchpackage.domain.entity.Moose
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Version select: select moose_id from mooses where moose_id =?
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Snapshot select: select moose_.moose_id, moose_.mooseling_1_id as mooselin3_37_, moose_.mooseling_2_id as mooselin4_37_, moose_.other_num as other_nu2_37_ from mooses moose_ where moose_.moose_id=?
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Insert 0: insert into mooses (mooseling_1_id, mooseling_2_id, other_num, moose_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Update 0: update mooses set mooseling_1_id=?, mooseling_2_id=?, other_num=? where moose_id=?
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Delete 0: delete from mooses where moose_id=?
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Identity insert: insert into mooses (mooseling_1_id, mooseling_2_id, other_num) values (?, ?, ?)
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.b.i.spaces.QuerySpacesImpl       : Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:0> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@7ec9780b]
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker   : Visiting attribute path : mooseling1
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.b.i.spaces.QuerySpacesImpl       : Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:1> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@7101fb1c]
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker   : Visiting attribute path : mooseling1.gooseling
2021-02-18 15:20:29.423 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.b.i.spaces.QuerySpacesImpl       : Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:2> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@4c974fe8]
2021-02-18 15:20:29.424 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker   : Visiting attribute path : mooseling1.gooseling.gooseData
2021-02-18 15:20:29.424 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker   : Visiting attribute path : mooseling2
2021-02-18 15:20:29.424 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.b.i.spaces.QuerySpacesImpl       : Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:3> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@3c88bef5]
2021-02-18 15:20:29.424 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker   : Visiting attribute path : mooseling2.gooseling
2021-02-18 15:20:29.424 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker   : Property path deemed to be circular : mooseling2.gooseling
2021-02-18 15:20:29.424 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.p.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker   : Visiting attribute path : otherNum
2021-02-18 15:20:29.424 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] lanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy : Building LoadPlan...
2021-02-18 15:20:29.424 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] h.l.p.e.i.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor : processing queryspace <gen:0>
2021-02-18 15:20:29.425 DEBUG 7909 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.build.spi.LoadPlanTreePrinter    : LoadPlan(entity=com.fetchpackage.domain.entity.Moose)
```

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "moose-mooseling-gooseling-entity-graph",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "mooseling1", subgraph = "mooseling-gooseling-subgraph"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "mooseling2", subgraph = "mooseling-gooseling-subgraph"),
    },
    subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(
            name = "mooseling-gooseling-subgraph",
            attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("gooseling")
            }
        )
    }
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "mooses")
public class Moose {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer mooseId;

  @Column
  @NotNull
  private Integer otherNum;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "mooseling_1_id")
  private Mooseling mooseling1;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "mooseling_2_id")
  private Mooseling mooseling2;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mooselings")
public class Mooseling {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer mooselingId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "gooseling_id")
  private Gooseling gooseling;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gooselings")
public class Gooseling {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer gooselingId;

  @Column
  @NotNull
  private Integer gooseData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has to do with circularity, but since you are not sharing your whole model, it's hard to say for sure. The problem with fetching an object graph from a relational structure is, that it could have cycles which you can't model with plain joins in SQLs. So Hibernate has to stop joining at some point and load the rest with dedicated select statements.

First of all, don't use EAGER fetching. It will bite you later. Always use LAZY fetching for associations. Then you can use entity graphs or join fetch in a HQL query to join only the associations that you actually want for a use case.

Comment: Good Guess.  There is a circular reference back to User from the roles, but I don't understand why it fetches all the details of the first user in 1 query, but the second user is hydrated with multiple SELECT statements for all the other related entities.

Comment: Maybe that specific user is somehow part of a different association which is lazy? Really, I can only guess since I don't see the whole model, but like I wrote. I would suggest you rather use entity graphs or join fetches to control this manually.